# Custom table with tabularx and multicolumns and multirows

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, multirow

I wanted to create a custom table with latex but I have an issue concerning the size of my table which not ends at the end of the width of the document. I don't understand why because 5x0.2\textwidth = 1 \textwidth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 right= 10mm,
 top=10mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth} | 
  }
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{logo} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C A}                  & M     \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre}                          & R    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & a & b & c & B   \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & d & e & f & Autres \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & h & i & j & DATE   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Does the table slightly stick out into the margin? Maybe the cell size doesn't factor in the seps on the left and right.

Comment: Just change `m{.2\textwidth}` with `X` (there is no sense in using `tabularx` without automatically-adjustable columns marked by `X`). You also have a warning from geometry you should consider

Comment: "5x0.2\textwidth = 1 \textwidth" -> this does not take into account the spacing before/after and in between columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `tabularx` table should has at least one column of X or from it derived type
- if some columns should have different width, you can define ratios between them or write some columns as `p{<width>}` or `m{<width>}`
- in your case I would rather use `tabularray` package instead of `tabularx` since

  - code is shorter,
  - cells' contents is better vertical spaced (centered)
  - if needed, it is simple change ratio between columns width

Example, when all columns has the same width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
          total={170mm,257mm},
          hmargin=10mm,
          top=10mm,
          }
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                      colspec = {*{5}{X[c]}}
                      }
\SetCell[r=5]{c}    logo
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} C A                 
        &   &   &   M               \\  
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} Titre
        &   &   &   R               \\
    & a & b & c &   B               \\
    & d & e & f &   Autres          \\
    & h & i & j &   DATE            \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and a case that cells has different widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
          total={170mm,257mm},
          hmargin=10mm,
          top=10mm,
          }
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                      colspec = {X[0.8, c] X[c] X[2, c] X[c] X[1.2, c]}
                      }
\SetCell[r=5]{c}    logo
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} C A                 
        &   &   &   M               \\  
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} Titre
        &   &   &   R               \\
    & a & b & c &   B               \\
    & d & e & f &   Autres          \\
    & h & i & j &   DATE            \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree: the new tabular packages (tabularray and nicematrix especially) are the way to go for "fancy" tabular structures.

Answer (score 6):

I have a working (not perfect) code that done this output:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=10mm,
    right= 10mm,
    top=10mm,
}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
            | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.18\textwidth}
            | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.18\textwidth}
            | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.18\textwidth}
            | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.18\textwidth}
            | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.18\textwidth} | 
        }
        \cline{1-5}
        \multirow{5}{*}{logo} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C A}      & M     \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre}                          & R    \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & a & b & c & B   \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & d & e & f & Autres \\ \cline{2-5} 
        & h & i & j & DATE   \\ \cline{1-5}
    \end{tabularx}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabularx` table should has at least one column of `X` or from it derived type.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 %total={170mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 right= 10mm,
 top=10mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
  *{5}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}| 
  }
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{logo} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C A}                  & M     \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre}                          & R    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & a & b & c & B   \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & d & e & f & Autres \\ \cline{2-5} 
                      & h & i & j & DATE   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The `X` column will stretch to fill the available space, which must take into account the vertical lines and the intercolumn space too. It's the only reason for the existence of the `tabularx` package... otherwise you can just go with a normal `tabular*` environment.

You can also use multipliers to avoid re-type the same thing 5 times.

I also removed one the `total` specifier in geometry: if you give paper size, left and right margin, you have fully specified the dimensions...

[image]

Comment: Your approach works perfectly but if I want to specify the size of each column how can I do ?

Comment: You must choose a size that fits, taking into account the intercolumn space and the width of the vertical rules. See, for example [Raffaele's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672928/38080). If it doesn't fit it doesn't fit... 

Comment: My solution fit. But Rmano solution is more elegant.

Comment: @Mo0nKizz If you want to specify the width of all columns, maybe a normal `tabular` would be better suited than a `tabularx`?

Answer (score 4):

`tabularx` provides `X`-type column, which adapts its width to the table. I would additionally suggest to define a custom column e.g. `Y` to avoid unnecessary repetition

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

The code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
     a4paper,
     % total={170mm,257mm},
     left=10mm,
     right= 10mm,
     top=10mm,
}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*5{Y|}}
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{logo} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C A}   & M \\ \cline{2-5} 
                          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
                          & a & b & c                  & B \\ \cline{2-5} 
                          & d & e & f                  & Autres \\ \cline{2-5} 
                          & h & i & j                  & DATE   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

and screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to *really* want a `tabularx` environment. In particular, you don't seem to require automatic line breaking in any cells.  Instead, it looks like you "just" want to create a table with five equal-width columns.

If this interpretation is correct, I suggest you (a) employ a `tabular` environment instead of `tabularx` environment and (b) load the `array` package and employ its `w` column type, which lets you specify the column's desired *usable* width. (In a LaTeX table, the column's total width is generally the sum of (a) the usable width and (b) any whitespace padding on either side, given by the parameter `\tabcolsep`.)

The following table has fives columns with usable widths of `2cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, top=10mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped "look"
\begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{w{c}{2cm}|} }
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{logo} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C A}   & M \\ \cline{2-5} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre} & R \\ \cline{2-5} 
   & a & b & c                  & B \\ \cline{2-5} 
   & d & e & f                  & Autres \\ \cline{2-5} 
   & h & i & j                  & DATE   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```